# Reducing CPU load/speed in FreeDOS

Tags: cpu-speed, freedos

I have recently installed FreeDOS on my old laptop, but the CPU is too fast for when I want to play games. Is there an option for me to reduce the CPU speed, so I can play retro games at normal speed?

I am new to FreeDOS, so please also give optimal settings.

Comment: Perhaps try a virtualizing application to run MS-DOS.  I just pulled up a DOS machine and the simple retro games worked properly. I don't think I can reduce my CPU to do this.

Comment: What game, exactly? How is "the CPU going too fast"?